# Apply GUI Mouse Filters to Touch Input

Tags: html, gdscript, godot3

I'm currently building an HTML5 game in Godot 3.5 for mobile. I'm using general `Control` nodes with `TouchScreenButton` children  for UI Controls to pause the game and to toggle sound/music and I'd like to avoid touch events on those buttons propagating to the player input. Setting the `mouse_filter` property to `Stop` does the job on PC and Android, but on iOS (in my case on my iPad) pressing the buttons also triggers the player input event.
If anyone has come across a similar issues, I'd be grateful to know how you solved them.

For reference, here is the input handling code for the player character:

```
func _unhandled_input(event) -> void:
    # if pressed:
    if Input.is_mouse_button_pressed(1) and _can_trigger:
            _charging = true
            _local_event_touch_point = make_input_local(event).position
            _touch_point = event.position
            _target = _local_event_touch_point
            _aiming_direction = position.direction_to(to_global(_target))
            _charging_bar.set_rotation( _charging_bar_rect.position.angle_to_point((_target)) + PI )
            # var grown_rect_charging = _charging_bar_rect.grow_individual(0,0,_charging_bar_rect.position.distance_to(_target),0)
            _charging_bar.visible = true
    
    if not event is InputEventMouseMotion and _can_trigger:
        if not Input.is_mouse_button_pressed(1):
            _charging_bar.visible = false
            var projectile = _projectiles[_active_projectile]
            _shoot(_aiming_direction, projectile, _shooting_speed)
            _shooting_speed = 0
            _charging = false
            _can_trigger = false
```

(using both emulation from touch to mouse and vice versa)

I tried

- modifying the touch emulation settings
- adjusting `mouse_filter`
- checking if my fat fingers are at fault ;)

Comment: If it works in Android but not in iOS it sounds like a platform specific bug. So I suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues